# Edge browser stopped working after upgrading to Windows 10 October 2018 Update (version 1809)

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

After upgrading to Windows 10 October 2018 Update (version 1809), Microsoft Edge browser can't load any web site or even resolve a DNS name. IE11, Chrome and Firefox still work OK.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the TCP/IPv6 on the adapter card fixed the issue for me. I did not have it enabled because my IP service provider does not use IPv6 and I had it disabled and Edge worked in that config until I updated to Windows 10 version 1809 in October. Spent several hours trying different suggestions that did not help. This fix took me 20 seconds to implement and get Edge connected to the internet.